# No bean named 'springbatch.readerDataSource' is defined

Tags: spring-batch

While executing my job I am getting below  exception

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'springbatch.readerDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springbatch.readerDataSource' is defined
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)

Note -- I am not creating seperate reader file .Just using JdbcCursorItemReader.

**My configuration file**

```
<bean id="itemReader" 
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="springbatch.batchDataSource"/>
        <property name="sql"  
                  value=
                    "select Cust_Id  from Customer   "/>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.insurance.premiumrecalculation.batch.CustDto" />
         </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="policy.premium.recalculation.PremiumRecalculationWriter" 
        class="com.insurance.premiumrecalculation.batch.PremiumRecalculationProcessWriter" scope="step"/>

    <batch:job id="policy.job.premiumRecalculation" 
        job-repository="springbatch.jobRepository" parent="springbatch.job.baseJob">

        <batch:step id="policy.step.premiumrecalculation" parent="springbatch.step.baseStep">
            <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="false" transaction-manager="powTransactionManager">                                   
                <batch:chunk commit-interval="10"                    
                    reader="itemReader"
                    writer="policy.premium.recalculation.PremiumRecalculationWriter"/>                    
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The source of this error is the following line:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="springbatch.batchDataSource"/>
```

Which means that you need a bean definition with id "springbatch.batchDataSource" configured as a data source for your environment which seems to not exist. You may use the following as a template; do not forget to provide your database driver and connection information.

```
<bean id="springbatch.batchDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Comment: In my spring configuration file 'springbatch.batchDataSource' is already cofigured .Also in my xml I am using springbatch.batchDataSource but it is throwing exception for 'springbatch.readerDataSource'.